# Sripted fields in Kibana: adding values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Given the following `Foo` entry which is stored in an ElasticSearch index :

```
"Foo": {
  "x":"500",
  "y":"200"
}
```

What is the correct syntax to create a sripted field within Kibana which adds the `X` and `Y` values together?

Answer (score 3):

If you index a document as follows

```
PUT scripted/doc/1
{
  "Foo": {
    "x":500,
    "y":200
  }
}
```

Then the syntax to sum the fields up in a scripted field is:

```
doc['Foo.x'].value + doc['Foo.y'].value
```

The `x` and `y` fields must be numeric fields. If you index them as strings you will get an error when trying to evaluate the scripted field.